# Problem in using "has"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am conveying the work status that I witnessed to my boss. I have doubt in below sentence

"SS top and trolley wheels are to be attached" or "SS top and trolley wheels has to be attached"

I am actually having a problem in visualizing the  has, have in the sentence. I just seeing and using them based on the grammar, rule but I could not actually visualize the sentence. is there some technique or something should I practice to remember?

Comment: ***wheels*** are plural, so your second version would need to be ***have** to be attached*. In practice, for a "work status" report most people wouldn't bother including a "finite, tensed, inflected" verb *(**are/have**)* at all. Other than that, I personally would say ***are*** is more likely when describing current status *(awaiting "attachment")*, whereas ***have*** works a bit better if you're telling someone *what they have to do [next]* within an ongoing / incomplete process. But approximately, they're just equivalent ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Note that *I **am** to retire at the end of the year* simply means that's will happen / is expected to happen. But *I **have** to retire at the end of the year* implies *I **must** retire then, I have no choice* (usually with the strong implication that if I *did* have a choice, I wouldn't). In short, using ***have to*** often implies necessity / obligation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thank you. I can use them correctly from now. I got the clue to visualize.

Comment: Note that in *spoken* English, the "phrasal verb" ***to have to** [do something] = to be obliged to do it* is often pronounced differently, which clearly reflects the idiomatic meaning (*I **have** to go now, He **has** to marry her now* are often pronounced ***haff, hass***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I came across one statement in my email "Your balance is exhausted, So your ads **have** stopped running.", If I write the same thing, I would write "Your balance is exhausted, so your ads stopped running." Probably both mean same. but I am not matching with the native.  Whats your comment on this?

Comment: *Your ads have stopped running* is just Present Perfect (***to have*** + Past Participle, describing "current" status relative to something in the past).  It's not related to ***to have to*** + unmarked infinitive, which for that statement would be *Your ads **have to stop** running* (often pronounced ***haff to***; they ***must / need to*** stop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one thing to attach, use *has*:

> The top **has** to be attached.

If it is more than one thing, use *have*:

> The SS top and wheels **have** to be attached.

If you think *have* sounds a little awkward there, you could use the verb *need* instead:

> The SS top and wheels **need** to be attached.

Comment: Thank you. I got the point. Now I got the confident on how to use.

Comment: I came across one statement in my email "Your balance is exhausted, So your ads have stopped running.", If I write the same thing, I would write "Your balance is exhausted, so your ads stopped running." Probably both mean same. but I am not matching with the native. Whats your comment on this?

Comment: @Aayvu.com - They effectively mean the same thing. *I quit dancing. I have quit dancing. I started a diet. I have started a diet. I chopped the onions. I have chopped the onions.* There really isn't much difference in meaning when the sentences are so simple. It's when certain time markers are added that the tense can become more important. *I washed the car yesterday.* (**Not**: *I have driven the car yesterday*.) *I have played goalie before, but it's been a long time since I was in net.*